# Alternatives to fseeko for Cygwin?

Tags: c, gcc, cygwin, posix, fseek

I have installed Cygwin (`CYGWIN_NT-6.1 AlexReynolds-PC 1.7.27(0.271/5/3) 2013-12-09 11:54 x86_64 Cygwin`) and GNU gcc/g++ 4.8.1.

I am compiling some tools that use POSIX C I/O routines, such as [`fseeko()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/fseek.html) and get a fatal error of the following sort:

```
 error: ‘fseeko’ was not declared in this scope
     int retValue = fseeko(stream, offset, whence);
```

Is `fseeko()` available in GNU gcc/g++ 4.8.1 on Cygwin? Are alternatives available which reliably honor a 64-bit offset, if not?

Answer (score 2):

`fseeko()` is available on my install of Cygwin (`CYGWIN_NT-6.1-WOW64 1.7.25(0.270/5/3) 2013-08-31 20:39 i686 Cygwin`) with GCC 4.7.3.  But if your install doesn't have it for some reason, you have a couple of alternatives:

- [`fseek()`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/fseek), with the caveat that the offset is likely limited to 32 bits instead of 64 (depending on `sizeof(long)`)
- [`fsetpos()`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/fsetpos), which takes an `fpos_t` for the offset.  However, `fpos_t` may be an opaque structure, so the only reliable way to use it is by calling `fgetpos()` to get the current position and then later call `fsetpos()` to restore the offset to the earlier position; you can't use it to seek to a particular offset otherwise.

Comment: Do you remember how you got `fseeko()` support? I've tried installing a couple different versions of gcc/g++ and neither seems to include it. The 64-bit support for offsets is a bit critical, so I'm trying to avoid `fseek()`.

Comment: @AlexReynolds: I've verified this answer. `fseeko()` exists in the current stock `libc` of both 32- and 64-bit Cygwin. If you save [this](http://pastebin.com/Yq3SHnzp) as `test.c` and say `make test`, it fails? Post the error if so. BTW, the function lives in `libc.a`, which is part of the `cygwin` package, not `gcc` or `g++`. What do you get for `cygcheck -c cygwin`?

Answer (score 1):

In my case the error was because I compiled the program with `--std=c++11`. Changing it to `--std=gnu++11` fixed the problem with compilation, but now I wonder if I should be using `fseeko` at all.

Then I peeked at Cygwin's `/usr/include/stdio.h` and discovered the same thing as [in this discussion](https://www.cygwin.com/ml/cygwin/2007-10/msg00595.html). There is an interesting reply:

> On Oct 29 14:32, Hongliang Wang wrote:
>
> > Hello all,
> >
> > My platform is WindowsXP+SP2, Cygwin DLL release version is 1.5.24-2
> >
> > I am trying to make my program support large files, so in stdio.h I found
> >
> > ```
> > 356 #ifdef __LARGE64_FILES
> > 357 #if !defined(__CYGWIN__) || defined(_COMPILING_NEWLIB)
> > ```
> >
> > However, when I tried to compile with `_COMPILING_NEWLIB`, it fails
>
> Never do that.  It should only be set when compiling newlib itself.
>
> > ```
> > $ gcc -Wall -D_COMPILING_NEWLIB test.c -o test
> > /cygdrive/c/DOCUME~1/wan/LOCALS~1/Temp/ccUmErSH.o:test.c:(.text+0x3a):
> > undefined reference to `_fopen64'
> > collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
> > ```
> >
> > It seems as if `fopen64` is mapped to `_fopen64`, while the latter is missing.
> >
> > Could anybody tell me how to compile with `_COMPILING_NEWLIB` flag or how does Cygwin support large files?
>
> Don't compile with `_COMPILING_NEWLIB`.  64 bit file access is the
>   natural file access type for Cygwin.  `off_t` is 8 bytes.  There are no
>   foo64 functions for that reason.  Just use `fopen` and friends and you
>   get 64 bit file access for free.
>
> Corinna
>
> --  Corinna Vinschen                  Please, send mails regarding Cygwin to Cygwin Project Co-Leader          cygwin AT cygwin DOT com
>   Red Hat

So there you have it.

Answer (score 0):

Just use fseek. As long as your long's are 64 bit, there's no difference.

Comment: This happens to work on 64-bit Cygwin where `sizeof(long)` is 8, but on 32-bit Cygwin `sizeof(long)` is 4, due to an old ABI decision on Microsoft's part. (Probably done to make the original Win16 WOW layer simpler.) I won't downvote, but I can't upvote since the real fix is to find out why the OP's system is missing `fseeko()`, which *should* be there.